# Installing SSIS package outside of SSIDB catalog

Tags: ssms, ssis, jobs

I'm trying to simplify deployment of a SSIS package to a remote server. At the moment, I have

- Local Visual Studio SSDT and SSIS package that has 4 connection managers - **DEV** environment
- Remote server with SQL, SSMS, and SSDT installed - **PROD** environment

The easiest way to deploy SSIS package from local computer to the remote server is to

- Create SSIDB catalog on the remote server
- Perform `Deploy` from Visual Studio and point it to the catalog created on the remote server

In this case everything works fine.

In the meantime, some **remote servers may not be accessible from Visual Studio** directly, so I'm trying to precompile SSIS package on local computer, upload to the remote server and add it to SQL server job as a single file, like it's described in this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210918171138/https://www.webdevdesigns.com/newsroom/scheduling-an-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2008/). The second screenshot in that article shows that I can choose `Package Source` = `File System` and specify a path to SSIS package file.

**The issue**

When I deploy SSIS package from Visual Studio to SSIDB catalog and create SQL server job using package in the catalog, it correctly shows 4 connection managers used by the package. When I create SQL server with manually uploaded SSIS package file, the tab `Data Sources` in SSMS shows empty list of connection managers. **Why in the second scenario, connection managers were not deployed with the package?**

Answer (score 0):

If VS doesn't have access to the remote server, you can build SSIS package, upload it to the remote server and install using SSMS.

- Build SSIS project to create **IPSAC** file in BIN folder
- Copy IPSAC file to the remote server
- Go to the remote server => **SSMS** => **Integration Services Catalog** => create new folder
- Created folder will have 2 sub-folders, one of them is **Projects**
- Click right mouse button on the Projects folder and choose option **Deploy**
- In the popup window, choose to deploy project and point it to IPSAC file